# EITHER all database queries should run OR none at all

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, async-await

In my `express` app I'm using `mongoose` as ODM, but the question is of generic nature. In my controller, I've multiple blocking queries like this (trimmed down version):

```
export const create = async (req, res) => {
    const existing_user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

    if (!existing_user) {
        const user          = await (new User(req.body)).save();
        const setting       = await (new Setting({ user_id: user })).save();
        return res.status(200).json({message:"User registered successfully.", user});
    }

    res.status(400).json({message: 'User with this email already exists.'});
};
```

In this controller, I'm registering a user and is creating his records in mutiple `collections`.

Here the problem is, if for some reason there is some error in creating a record in `setting` collection, it'll throw an error and will stop execution, but now the user will have a record in the `user` collection without having relevant record in the `setting` collection.

My question is, how can I make sure that it either sucessfully creates record in both collections, or in case of failure in any query, it should not create record in any collection. What should be my approach?

Comment: does mongodb support transactions? If so, that would be the way to go, if not, detect the failures and delete the previously created entries

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this behavior: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-transactions

Comment: Well, apparently it does seem that it should solve the issue. I'll definitely check it out. Thanks.